# Adobe AIR - My Mobile Services Don't Work

Tags: ipad, mobile, service, air, adobe

I am really close to being done with my app.  The layout is finally correct and scaling properly.  The only problem I have now is with my services.  When I click on the button that is supposed to load data from my database, nothing happens.  I set the endpoints of the services to point to my database on my website.  The app works in the simulator, but on my iPad, I get nothing.  So I have a couple of questions.  Does the .ipa file that you upload to an iPad contain all the folder structure for your services? Is there a descriptor setting that needs to be set to make sure that you have internet access on the device?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  The desktop version works, and it works in the mobile simulator, but not on the iPad??? I don't even know where to start with the debugging so any thoughts at all are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer about NSTransportSecurity

stackoverflow.com/questions/39849033/flash-cs6-as3-check-internet-connection-not-working-at-all/40101024#40101024

Comment: That turned out to be the exact cause of my problem. It was not that my services didn't work, but that Apple's mobile security was not allowing the connection until I added the correct descriptor file information. Thanks for the help!!